# Checking open rdp ports from script

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, tcpip

I need to find out what server ports are listening on port 3389. I have to check 2500 servers, some in different vlans, to make sure remote desktop is enabled.

Can netstat be used to check this and used against a ip range.. or would it be best to use powershell command

> new-object system.net.sockets.TCPclientList xsevernamex, 3389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nmap` is great for this:

```
nmap -v -p 3389 -iL list-of-hosts.txt -oX results.xml
```

will result in an XML file you can parse programatically, but other output options also exist.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer powershell. Let me know if this needs any adjustments. input.txt is just a list of computers.

```
$computers = Import-Csv input.txt -Header "Name" 
$output = @()

$computers | ForEach-Object {
    $current = "" | Select-Object "Name","RdpOpen"
    $result = Test-NetConnection $_.Name -CommonTCPPort RDP 

    $current.Name = $_.Name
    $current.RdpOpen = $result.TcpTestSucceeded
    $output += $current
}

$output | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Preferred answer over nmap.  PowerShell and Test-Netconnection come with Windows, gotta install nmap.